# Retrieve and decode value via PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I cann't achieve decoding of the value stored as such in MariaDB:

```
INSERT INTO tbl  
(password) 
VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT(%s,UNHEX(SHA2(%s,0))),$pass,"abcde");
```

using PHP script.
The code I'm using to decode the value is:

```
$enc = dibi::fetchSingle('
       SELECT password
       FROM cred
       WHERE *conditions*');

$password = dibi::fetchSingle('
       SELECT AES_DECRYPT(%bin,UNHEX(SHA2(%s,0))),$enc,'abcde');
```

Binary value is retrieved successfully in $enc but when I'm trying to var_dump a $password variable I'm getting a NULL result.

Please suggest possible problems, why the value is not decoded properly?
Is it a way to apply an AES_DECODE function on the fly, in the same SELECT statement?

Answer (score 0):

The scheme of encrypting a hash of a password is not secure. Instead simply use the PHP functions `password_hash` and `password_verify`, it is simple and secure.

Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security.

Encrypt passwords fails when the attacker gains access to the DB he also gets the encryption key.

Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.